# OOP design suggestion

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have set of files that needs to either emailed or FTPed(read from config). Before doing either of these I need to so some common operation on the files, like changing filenames, sanity check, so on.

```
        package Class::Foo::Partners;

    use Carp;
    use Data::Dumper;
    # Sanity check and Blessing
    sub new ($) {
        my $class = shift;
        my %attr = @_;
        Carp::confess('Config undefined') unless defined $attr{cfg};
        my $self = bless({}, $class);
        %$self = @_;
        return $self;
    }

    sub process {
        my $self = shift;

        my %filestoupload = ();
        if ($self->{dbh}->sql($sql, \%filestoupload)) {
            my $stats;
            if (defined $self->{cfg}->{$self->{section}}->{pdf_email_rcpt}) {
                $stats = Class::Foo::Email->new(section => $self->{cfg}->{$self->{section}}, filestoupload => \%filestoupload);
                $stats->sendfiles;
            } else {
                $stats = Class::Foo::FTP->new(section => $self->{cfg}->{$self->{section}}, filestoupload => \%filestoupload);
                $stats->sendfiles;
            }
        } elsif ($self->{dbh}->{_error}) {
            Carp::confess($self->{dbh}->{_error});
        } else {
            print "NO FILES";
        }
    }


    package Class::Foo::FTP;

    use Carp;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use POSIX qw( strftime );
    use File::Temp qw (tempdir) ;
    use File::Copy;
    use Net::FTP;

    # Sanity check and Blessing
    sub new ($) {
        my $class = shift;
        my %attr = @_;
        Carp::confess('Section undefined') unless defined $attr{section};
        Carp::confess('undefined ftp_host') unless defined $attr{section}->{ftp_host};


        my $self = bless({}, $class);
        %$self = @_;

        return $self;
    }

    sub sendfiles {
        my $self = shift;
        return unless(keys %{$self->{filestoupload}});
        #DO SOME COMMON TASK
        ..
        $self->ftp_connect();
        ..
        ..
    }

    package Class::Foo::Email;

    use Data::Dumper;
    use Mail::Sender;
    use POSIX qw( strftime );
    use File::Temp qw (tempdir) ;
    use File::Copy;

    sub new ($) {
        my $class = shift;
        my %attr = @_;
        Carp::confess('Config: undefined pdf_email_subject') unless defined $attr{section}->{pdf_email_subject};
        Carp::confess('Config: undefined pdf_email_from') unless defined $attr{section}->{pdf_email_from};
        my $self = bless({}, $class);
        %$self = @_;

        return $self;
    }

    sub sendfiles {
        my $self = shift;
        return unless(keys %{$self->{filestoupload}});
        #DO SOME COMMON TASK
        ..
        my $mailrcpt = $self->{section}->{pdf_email_rcpt};
        my $sender = new Mail::Sender {smtp => 'localhost', from => $self->{section}->{pdf_email_from}};
        $sender->MailFile({ to => $mailrcpt, 
                            subject => $self->{section}->{pdf_email_subject}, 
                            msg => "Attached is A1 of today's WSJE. ",
                            ctype => 'application/pdf',
                            file => @files } );

        $self->{uploaded_count} = @files;
    }
```

Where to do the common operation and when and how to call respective child classes?

Should I use abstraction?

thanks for your help

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do.  Which aspects of OOP are you having trouble with?  Do you have any code already written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the implementation of MT::FileMgr:

https://github.com/openmelody/melody/tree/master/lib/MT

It should give you a lot of ideas on how to do Perl OOP for something like this.